# how to run c++ file if header, class, and main are not in the same folder?

Tags: c++

The code::block IDE generates the following files:

- `./main.cpp`
- `./include/class.h`
- `./src/class.cpp` It include class.h with `#include "class.h"`

How can I run this set of files, with the three files in three different folders?

- First, this program can be run by clicking IDE "build and run" button.
- This program need to take some arguments, like `./a.out arg[1] arg[2]`. So I cannot input arguments by clicking "build and run" button, and thus I have to use g++ to compile an output first.
- But g++ is not smart enough as the IDE in finding the three files(I try `g++ -I./include main.cpp`, it seems that it has no problem with class.h file, but cannot find class.cpp file)

So how can I compile the three files in three different locations?

BTW, how could the class.h file find the class.cpp file in IDE/g++(scan all the files in the directory to see which contains the definition of the class functions?)?

Comment: You can specify a project's command-line arguments in the "project" menu of Code::Blocks.

Comment: Thank you very much! I got it. But does it mean I have to input my arguments from the menu every time I rerun the main.cpp file?

Comment: Only if you want to change them.  Or you can build in Code::Blocks and then run the resulting binary from the command prompt.

Comment: Thank you! How could code::block output a .out file? I chose "console application", and it only pop up a console with result when I run it. It does not output anything or give me any time to input the arguments.

Comment: It's time to go to the Code::Blocks website.  Stack Overflow isn't a discussion forum, but they have one.  Good luck!

Comment: OK, thank you very much!

Comment: You forgot to mention which IDE you're using. If it has build-and-run functionality it probably also has some way of only building the application.

Comment: You want `class.cpp` to include `class.h`, not the other way around...  Otherwise you'll run into all sorts of problems when you try to use your class from another file in addition to `main.cpp`

Comment: I am using code::blocks. It seems that the result .out file is in "\bin\Debug" folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally one would expect that the IDE has some function to just build the application, especially when there's a function to build-and-run. In addition there are those that have the possibility to supply command line arguments for the program so build-and-run will run with supplied arguments.

You have to supply the source files and the search path for includes, normally one would write:

```
g++ -o exec-file-name -I./include main.cpp src/class.cpp
```

but that may depend a bit on how you include the header file. Another note is that you normally don't compile the header file separately - it's included when you compile the `.cpp` files that includes it.

If on the other hand you actually want to do what you write (compile the `.h` file that includes the `.cpp` file - which is higly unorthodox) you would do:

```
g++ -c -I./src include/class.h
g++ -c main.cpp
g++ -o exec-file-name main.o class.o
```

where you need to replace the `.o` extension if your platform uses another extension. Note that in this case you should probably not include `class.h` from `main.cpp` since that could lead to duplicate symbols.

Comment: Thank you! If we have a lot of class(.cpp) files, we have to manually input/specify all the related .cpp files for g++(either type it in command line or in makefile), right? [I only have one class cpp file right now, just wondering how people usually deal with this kind of thing.]

Comment: I think the normalest way is to build it using some kind of build system (make, maven, scons, msbuild or whatever). In some cases it is built from the IDE, but even then it's normally just a front end to a build system. Only for trivial builds it's suitable to call `gcc` directly from command line.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bad idea to `#include` source files. But this will do it:

```
g++ -I./include -Isrc main.cpp
```

Comment: It seems that this does not work for me. It still said "undefined reference to [the class function]"

Comment: It works when I ran `g++ -I./include ./src/class.cpp main.cpp`. Well it seems that this is not a good way to do this.

Comment: @breezeintopl: Are you sure that `main` #includes `class.h`, and that `class.h` #includes `class.cpp`?

Comment: No. class.cpp includes class.h but not vise ver sa. I will try to include both. Thank you!

Comment: @breezeintopl: *Stop!* You said in the question that `class.h` #includes `class.cpp`, which would be bad. Now you say that `class.cpp` #includes `class.h`, which would be correct. Which is it?

Comment: So sorry for the confusion. I corrected my question. `class.cpp` includes `class.h`.